# How do you write the shorthand for a nested class that has already been declared in SASS / SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

As you can see, I have a variation for `.mainContainer` in the form of `&--alt`. However, I need to repeat `.mainContainer__content` inside the `&--alt` class to say that if there's a `.mainContainer--alt` in the parent container, then `.mainContainer__content` will have a different styling.

Is there a better way to write this as it seems to defeat the purpose of using the shorthand version if I am going to write out the complete class name in this particular example.

CSS:

```
.mainContainer {

    // SOME CSS properties

    &--alt {

        .mainContainer__content {

            // SOME CSS properties

        }
    }

    &__content {

        // SOME CSS properties

    }

}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="mainContainer__content">
        // some style
      </div>
    </div>
```

HTML (with alt):

```
   <div class="mainContainer mainContainer--alt">
      <div class="mainContainer__content">
        // some other style
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share your DOM as well?

Comment: @DragonKnight Added..

Comment: I was guessing. that's not the proper way to write css. ill modify your code using attribute selectors in css but I dont recommend to write it this way. use SASS and sort of object oriented css.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the main class in a variable like this

```
.mainContainer {
  $self: &;
    // SOME CSS properties
    &--alt {
        #{$self}__content {
            // SOME CSS properties
        }
    }

    &__content {
        // SOME CSS properties
    }
}
```

Another option is to put the modifier on the
`.mainContainer__content` e.g. `.mainContainer__content--alt`

Comment: Nice solution indeed!

Answer (score 0):

check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_attribute_selectors.asp
I uesed attribute selector where class ends with `[class$="value"]`

```
.mainContainer {

    // SOME CSS properties

    &[class$="--alt"] {

        .mainContainer__content {

            // SOME CSS properties

        }
    }

    &[class$="__content"] {

        // SOME CSS properties

    }

}
```

but again I dont recommend write it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this.   

 @mixin generate-sizes($class) {
        .#{$class}__content {
           font-size: 12px;
          }
        .#{$class}--alt {
          font-size: 14px; 
        }
    }
    @include generate-sizes("mainContainer");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.